# flink on kubernetes: Can I define separate numbers for memory request and memory usage?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink

We're using the Flink native kubernetes approach in Application Mode as documented here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/resource-providers/native_kubernetes/

```
flink run-application
    --target kubernetes-application \
    -Djobmanager.memory.process.size=3G \
    -Dtaskmanager.memory.process.size=3G \
    -Dkubernetes.jobmanager.cpu=0.05 \
    -Dkubernetes.jobmanager.cpu.limit-factor=4.0 \
    -Dkubernetes.taskmanager.cpu=0.1 \
    -Dkubernetes.taskmanager.cpu.limit-factor=6.0 \
    [more params...]
    my.jar
```

Now I would like to define a memory minimum that each pod gets even if it doesn't do anything and a memory maximum that it can use when it has something to do (resources request and limit in k8s terms).

In above example I managed to define it for cpu, but I couldn't find the correct parameters for memory. Can someone help me find the right approach?